# what is wrong with MySQL select Store Procedure with dynamic query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

i have tried to create MySQL store procedure in that i want to make dynamic query.
code on which i working..

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `test`.`selectp` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `selectp`(in a_str_Condition varchar(500))

BEGIN
 SET @Query = 'SELECT * from test123';
IF a_str_Condition != ''
THEN
   SET @strCondition = CONCAT(' WHERE ? ');
   SET @param = a_str_Condition;
ELSE
 SET @strCondition = ' Order by aaa desc';
END IF

SET @Query = CONCAT(@Query, @strCondition );

    PREPARE stmt FROM @Query;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @param;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

here i want pass parameter as `aaa = 3` and concat it with mysql query, but it show me error as below.

[image]

please let me clear on this store procedure. Any help will be Appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to answer to your *...what is wrong with MySQL select Store Procedure..?*

As others mentioned you have `;` missing. That only solves a syntax error.
But you have bigger problems with the way you try to construct your query and `EXECUTE` it:

1. You're incorrectly trying to treat all where conditions as one parameter with `WHERE ?`, instead of parameterizing values like `WHERE id = ?`
2. In case you don't pass a condition you can't use `USING` in `EXECUTE`. It'll fail.

Now since you don't execute your query multiple times,  you pass conditions as a string anyway, and it seems that you're more after flexibility than security,  IMHO there is no much sense in using parameters here.

That being said a more succinct version of your SP might look like this

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE selectp(IN _conditions VARCHAR(500), IN _orderby VARCHAR(500))
BEGIN
  SET @sql = CONCAT(
    'SELECT * FROM test123 WHERE 1 = 1',
    COALESCE(CONCAT(' AND ', NULLIF(_conditions, '')), ''),
    ' ORDER BY ',
    COALESCE(NULLIF(_orderby, ''), 'id DESC')
    );
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Usage examples:

```
-- default parameters either with null or an empty string
CALL selectp('', '');
CALL selectp(NULL, NULL);
-- set where conditions
CALL selectp('id IN(1, 3)', NULL);
-- set order by
CALL selectp(NULL, 'col1 DESC, col2');
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea2ca)** demo

Comment: thanks for you answer it really solve my problem and `+1 for SQLFiddle`

Answer (score 1):

You've lost a semicolon after `END IF`.

And that's what mysql is pointed you to - it always shows you the expression part it couldn't parse. So always look at the code right before the one from the error description.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but when i execute store procedure using `CALL selectp('aaa = 2');`, its return me 0 rows, whats the problem now..? in table there is row for aaa = 2.

Comment: @Vijay Ramani: how is it relevant to the question? Your question was about syntax error. I've answered to it. If you have another question - accept one of given answers and ask again.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a semi column after the END IF statement:

```
ELSE
 SET @strCondition = ' Order by aaa desc';
END IF; //add semicolumn here
```

Before this line:

```
SET @Query = CONCAT(@Query, @strCondition );
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but when i execute store procedure using `CALL selectp('aaa = 2');`, its return me 0 rows, whats the problem now..? in table there is row for aaa = 2.

Comment: @VijayRamani Try by returning the query and check what query you are getting and you will get the exact problem.